# SEARCH FIELD COLUMNS RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

3.5 and ruby 1.8.7

I want to know how to create a multiple  search field using only 1 text field also it can search 4 columns from the same table (name, name2,last_name,last_name2)

```
VALUES ====>  name, name2, last_name and last_name2
TABLE ====> PROJECTS

FOR EXAMPLE =>   "Jagjit Smith   Sgnit     Robertson"
                  :name  :name2 :last_name :last_name 2

                 "Jagjit Smith"
                  :name :name2

                 "Jagjit Roberton"
                  :name   :last_name2

                  "Sgnit     Robertson"
                 :last_name :last_name2
```

I did my controller , model and view but seems that i have sql injection problem but i want the code solution no gems , please someone can edit this or help me with this problem??? i searched many posts and solutions but are for rails 3 using gems

```
 ***************HERE IS MY CONTROLLER****************
 Here some people told me that my code has vulnerability 
 is there any other way to make this code more cheape without write 24 conditions????

class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

def index
         @projects = Project.find(:all, :conditions => "(
          name LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\" OR
          name2 LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\" OR
          last_name LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\"OR 
          last_name2 LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\" OR 
          (concat(name, \" \", last_name) LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\") OR
          (concat(name, \" \", name2    ) LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\") OR 
          (concat(last_name, \" \", last_name2) LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\") OR 
          (concat(name, \" \", name2, \" \",last_name, \" \",last_name2) LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\") OR
          (concat(name, \" \", name2, \" \",last_name) LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\")
                           )")
    end
 end
```

Here is my model is empty i need help here please maybe other example or add something

```
       *****HERE IS MY MODEL***************

       class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

       end
```

Here is my view ,actually it is working and has 24 conditionals, i need the trick to solve problems with vulnerability and also without write lots of conditionals

```
      ************HERE IS MY VIEW **************     

     <form name="search-form" id="search-form">
        <%= text_field_tag "query", params[:query], :autocomplete => 'on' %>
     </form>
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using gems?

Comment: How about at the very least you don't just shove params into a string??? And if those are your search conditions, those are your search conditions.

Comment: Do you know the code? how can you resolve this?

Comment: Levi Stanley, if i use gems how should be the code according to this?

Answer (score 0):

OK... now if your search string is complex, you can use a gem called Squeel..

[Checkout Squeel..](https://github.com/ernie/squeel)

for example,

`name LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\"` will become `name.like_any params[:query]`

Look at the Git hub page... they have many examples on how to use Squeel...